# Error in calculating median image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

```
image=imread('Tiger.jpg');
%figure,imshow(uint8(image)),title('Before applying Median Filter');


[rows, cols]=size(image);
B=zeros(rows, cols);

for rowNo=2:rows-1
    for colNo=2:cols-1
         K=image(rowNo-1:rowNo+1,colNo-1:colNo+1);

    B(rows,cols)=median(K);
   end
end


figure,imshow(uint8(B)),title('After applying Median Filter');
```

I want to calculate the median of my image without using built in function , but i give me the errors ,can any one please help me out
Error

```
??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in ==> Quest_2median at 18
    B(rows,cols)=median(K);
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Could you edit your question to include these errors?

Comment: Your error is that `median` makes a vector (but you need a scalar), so convert `K` to vector before `median`: `B(rows,cols)=median(reshape(K,1,9));`, but better use medfilt2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code is a better implementation:

```
image=imread('../SampleImages/cat.jpg');
%figure,imshow(uint8(image)),title('Before applying Median Filter');
image = rgb2gray(image);
image = imnoise(image,'salt & pepper');
[rows, cols]=size(image);
B=zeros(rows, cols);

for rowNo=2:rows-1
    for colNo=2:cols-1
        K=image(rowNo-1:rowNo+1,colNo-1:colNo+1);
K = reshape (K,1,9);
B(rowNo,colNo)=median(K);
    end
end

figure,imshow(uint8(image)),title('Before applying Median Filter');
figure,imshow(uint8(B)),title('After applying Median Filter');
```

The note is median function takes a vector and when you pass a matrix it gives a row vector including median of each column.